# How to export filtered table data to PDF in Filament using DomPDF?

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm new to Filament and I have a question. I'm using default filters in my Filament project, I want to export only filtered table data to a PDF using DomPDF. For instance, 10 records are in the database, and after using the filter only 3 reflect in the table, now I want these 3 records to be exported and generate a PDF. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried many things but no success, below is my last try.

**below code for TransactionResource.php**

```
public static $filteredData = [];
    
public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    $filteredData['selectedRecords'] = $table->getFilters();
    return $table
    ->columns([
            TextColumn::make('owner.name')->sortable()->searchable(),
            TextColumn::make('department.name')->sortable()->searchable(),
            TextColumn::make('category.category_code')->sortable()->searchable(),
            TextColumn::make('description')->sortable()->searchable(),
            TextColumn::make('receipt_number')->sortable()->searchable(),
            TextColumn::make('receipt_date')->date()->sortable(),
            TextColumn::make('receipt_amount')->sortable()->searchable(),
            LinkTextColumn::make('Actions') // Using the custom column class
            ->link(fn ($value, $record) => route('report.test', ['filteredData' => $record->getFilters()]))
    ])
        ->filters([
            SelectFilter::make('category')->relationship('category', 'name'),
            SelectFilter::make('subcategory')->relationship('subcategory', 'name'),
            SelectFilter::make('department')->relationship('department', 'name'),
            SelectFilter::make('owner')->relationship('owner', 'name'),
            
            Filter::make('receipt_date')
            ->form([
                Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('receipt_date_from'),
                Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('receipt_date_to'),
            ])
            ->query(function (Builder $query, array $data): Builder {
                return $query
                    ->when(
                        $data['receipt_date_from'],
                        fn (Builder $query, $date): Builder => $query->whereDate('receipt_date', '>=', $date),
                    )
                    ->when(
                        $data['receipt_date_to'],
                        fn (Builder $query, $date): Builder => $query->whereDate('receipt_date', '<=', $date),
                    );
            }),
        ])
        ->actions([
            Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
        ])
        ->bulkActions([
            Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
        ]);
        
    
}


// function to send the filtered data to the PDFController
public function sendToAnotherController(Table $table)
{        
    $filteredData[] = $table->filters([]);
    return redirect()->route('PDFReportController', ['filteredData' => $filteredData]);
}
```

**below code for PDFReportController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Owner;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class PDFReportController extends Controller
{   
    public function downloadReport(Request $request) {
       $filteredData = $request->input();
       dd($filteredData);
       $transactions = Transaction::all();
    
       $pdf = PDF::loadview('reportPDF', $filteredData);
       $pdf->set_paper('letter', 'landscape');
       return $pdf->stream('report.pdf');
    }    
}
```

**below is the result**

[result-jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t22bi.jpg)